# #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1060

Why I get #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `tips` `t` LEFT JOIN
tip_usage ON tip_usage.tip_id=t.id GROUP BY t.id) sq
```

Comment: Are you aware, that since it's a LEFT join, rows in joined table do not influence number of rows returned by COUNT(*)? You might just as well do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tips`

Comment: No! Wait!... there's a GROUP BY... but no aggregating function... this query just makes no sense.

Comment: Is `id` a `PRIMARY KEY` on `tips`? If you don't have a record for a tip in `tip_usage`, should this tip be counted?

Comment: @Mchl: it's the same as `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. It could make sense if there were duplicates on `t.id`.

Comment: If you need `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` you use `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` not some trick that might or might not work depending on SQL mode set. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Probably because the * in `select *` selects two columns with the same name from `tip_usage` and `tips`.

Comment: ... and "any columns in the subquery select list [must have](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) unique names."

Answer (score 12):

Probably it's because the inner select yields two columns with the name `id`. Since you are not using those columns, you can just change the select to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT t.id FROM `tips` `t` 
LEFT JOIN tip_usage ON tip_usage.tip_id=t.id 
GROUP BY t.id) sq
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM    tips
```

, there is no need in a join.

Are you sure you didn't want an `INNER JOIN` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, renaming into select clause saved me

```
SELECT people.id, vehicle.id ...
```

I renamed it with **AS** keyword

```
SELECT people.id AS person_id, vehicle.id ...
```