# How to create view in query having JOINS?

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-error-1060

Hello I am not able to create view for following query.

```
create view  my_View as 
select *  from product p 
LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON (p.product_id=pd.product_id)
```

I have two tables

TABLE1 :- 
**Product** with column as :-  product_id, column2,column3

TABLE2 :- **Product_Description** with column as:- product_id , column4,column5. 
Here product_id is foreign key for Product table.

Following is the error I am getting

> Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'product_id'

I am using mysql workbench to run my queries. Looking at the error, I understand that I need to assign alias. But I am required to join more than 5-8 tables thats the reason I am looking for better solution.

Comment: Your `SELECT *` is returning both columns named `product_id` - instead of using `SELECT *` list your columns such as `select product_id, column2, column3`, etc. You shouldn't need to return `product_id` twice.

Comment: As mentioned I understood that approach. But I thought if there is some other way.

Comment: @bluefeet If you would have gone through full description than you would have not echoed what I already wrote.

Comment: I did read your full question, using `SELECT *` is a bad habit.

Comment: @Ashish You need to **type**. There is no magic solution for disambiguation of columns due to laziness.

Comment: possible duplicate of [#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815627/1060-duplicate-column-name-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution in your case is to use `using` instead of `on`:

```
create view  my_View as 
    select * 
    from product p LEFT JOIN
         product_description pd 
         USING (product_id);
```

In general, though, you should list the columns explicitly in the `select` rather than using `*`.

Comment: Not my DV but I don't think that will resolve the error.

Comment: @bluefeet . . . (1) It should.  (2) It does in SQL Fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b53a0.  Can you please remove the downvotes?

Comment: As I said, it's not my DV so I can't remove it.

Comment: IMHO this "solution" is extremely brittle and not a good suggestion at all. It relies on the assumption that the joining key is the only column name shared between the two tables today, and that that will remain true in the future as well. This breaks if both tables have a column called `ModifiedDate`, for example.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The suggestion is to list all the columns (see what I write after the suggestion).  The `using` is a way to get around the particular problem in the OP's original question (which only involved two tables).

Comment: But `USING` only works around the key columns, not any others. While that may work given the limited information the OP has provided, and in this specific scenario only, it is still a dangerous thing to advocate in general. Remember that answers here are not just for *this OP*.

Answer (score 2):

The Error is coming due to same column name in both the tables, second thing is its never a good practice to fetch all records in views by using `*` until and unless you really want all records from all table that you are using in join condition.

What you can do is select records specific to your view, like

```
select p.*,pd.somefield  from product p 
LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON (p.product_id=pd.product_id)
```

In the above query your `product_id` is fetched from `product` table only and you can fetch only necessary fields from `product_description`  table

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT *` will select all columns from both tables in the join. But both tables have a column called `product_id`, so you'll get two columns in the view with the same name.

You need to list out all the columns, so you can give an alias to `product_description.product_id` to distinguish it:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.column2, p.column3, pd.product_id AS pd_id, pd.column4, pd.column5
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN product_description AS pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
```