# Creating view in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

When i try to create view like this CREATE VIEW data2tables AS

```
SELECT * FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Computers c ON e.id = c.id WHERE e.name = 'Georgi' AND c.department = 'Sales'
```

it gives me error saying that #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id',and i have no idea how to fix it or why does the error occur.

```
CREATE VIEW data2tables AS 
SELECT * FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Computers c 
ON e.id = c.id 
WHERE e.name = 'Georgi' AND c.department = 'Sales';
```

**#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815627/1060-duplicate-column-name-id)

Answer (score 1):

Your table `Employees` and the table `Computers` both have a column named `id`.

When you say `SELECT * FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Computers c...` you are basically saying *give me every column 'Employees' AND 'Computers'* so you are getting a duplicate of `id` (and any other column in there that may be the same name).

With a `VIEW` you want to select a defined set of results so I would recommend explicitly specifying the columns you want from both tables.

If you require `id` from both tables I would recommend giving the joined table (Computers) id column an alias...something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW data2tables AS 
SELECT e.id, e.fieldA, e.fieldN, c.id as ComputersId, c.fieldA, c.fieldN 
FROM Employees e 
INNER JOIN Computers c ON e.id = c.id 
WHERE e.name = 'Georgi' AND c.department = 'Sales';
```

That method of aliasing will also apply to any other cross-over column names you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify columns for Computer's table.

```
CREATE VIEW data2tables AS 
SELECT e.*, c.[column_name].... FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Computers c 
ON e.id = c.id 
WHERE e.name = 'Georgi' AND c.department = 'Sales';
```