# Join into pivot (?)

Tags: mysql

I wonder how to replace such a table
(the table is the result of 3x LEFT JOIN)

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN items on users.id = items.id
LEFT JOIN items_additional on users.id = items_additional.items_id
LEFT JOIN items_ask_user on users.id = items_ask_user.items_id';
```

| ID | item_id | name | surname | addition | question | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Gladys | Warner | hot-dog | mayo | 14 |
| 2 | 1 | Gladys | Warner | pizza | chilli | 11 |
| 3 | 2 | Harrison | Croft | pizza |  |  |
| 4 | 2 | Harrison | Croft | burger | chilli | 11 |
| 5 | 2 | Harrison | Croft | hod-dog | mayo | 14 |

to somthing like

| ID | item_id | name | surname | addition | addition2 | addition3 | question1 | question2 | question3 | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Gladys | Warner | hot-dog | pizza | - | mayo | chilli | - | 25 |
| 2 | 2 | Harrison | Croft | pizza | burger | hod-dog | chilli | mayo | - | 25 |

the number of additions or questions may increase or decrease, depending on person.

## Edit

```
SET @sql = NULL;

WITH cte AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS idx
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN items on users.id = items.id
    LEFT JOIN items_additional on users.id = items_additional.items_id
    LEFT JOIN items_ask_user on users.id = items_ask_user.items_id
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT('MAX(IF(rn_add = ', cte.idx, ', additional_option_name, NULL)) AS additional_option_name', cte.idx, ','
                  'MAX(IF(rn_qst = ', cte.idx, ', ask_user, NULL)) AS ask_user', cte.idx
       )) INTO @sql
FROM cte;

SET @cte = 'WITH cte AS(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, surname ORDER BY IF(additional_option_name IS NULL, 1, 0), `event_items`.`id`) AS rn_add, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, surname ORDER BY IF(ask_user IS NULL, 1, 0), `event_items`.`id`) AS rn_qst 
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN event_items on users.id = event_items.id
    LEFT JOIN event_items_additional on users.id = event_items_additional.items_id
    LEFT JOIN event_items_ask_user on users.id = event_items_ask_user.items_id';

SET @sql = CONCAT(@cte,
                  'SELECT `event_items`.`id`, user_id, name, surname,',
                  @sql,
                  ',SUM(additional_option_price) AS additional_option_price FROM cte GROUP BY user_id, name, surname'
);

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

## Edit2

Schema demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZ1nYthiEMsJxKcUgUrGSp/2)

Comment: Do you really need separate (and therefore dynamic) columns for *addition* and *question*? You could just aggregate the values as strings.

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: i tried using pivot from SQL Server before i notice that MySQL can't do the same way @lemon

Comment: @Hub is the schema fixed (max 3 additions/questions), or is it dynamic (unknown number of additions/questions) as supposed by Stu?

Comment: Yes i can but I am curious if it is possible differently @Stu

Comment: @lemon it's dynamic

Comment: A dynamic solution is feasible but more expensive than Stu's smart idea. If you're more interested in the dynamic one, I'll leave an answer below. @Hub

Comment: Thanks. @lemon
I need to export the table to Excel, which makes the dynamic solution seem more flexible in this case.

Comment: Also thanks @Stu for nice idea :) it will be useful to me many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the dynamic solution is based on the static one, for reasons of clarity I'll first explain the static one by assuming that, as in the example your provided, there are exactly 3 fields at max, for *addition* and *question* fields.

Let's look at **the static solution** first, by assuming that we have specifically 3 fields. In this case what you can do is compute a row number for each *addition* and *question*, which will be used to match the specific value at the required index for each of the three fields *addition1*, *addition2* and *addition3* (same goes for *question*), using an `IF` statement. In order to remove the NULL values that are generated by this statement, we can select the maximum value and aggregate over *item_id*, *name* and *surname*

```
WITH cte AS(
       SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY name, surname
               ORDER     BY IF(addition IS NULL, 1, 0), 
                            ID                ) AS rn_add, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY name, surname
               ORDER     BY IF(question IS NULL, 1, 0), 
                            ID                ) AS rn_qst
       FROM tab 
)
SELECT item_id AS ID,
       item_id,
       name,
       surname,
       MAX(IF(rn_add = 1, addition, NULL)) AS addition1,
       MAX(IF(rn_add = 2, addition, NULL)) AS addition2,
       MAX(IF(rn_add = 3, addition, NULL)) AS addition3,
       MAX(IF(rn_qst = 1, question, NULL)) AS question1,
       MAX(IF(rn_qst = 2, question, NULL)) AS question2,
       MAX(IF(rn_qst = 3, question, NULL)) AS question3,
       SUM(amount)                                         AS amount
FROM cte
GROUP BY item_id,
         name,
         surname
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cXVEi2wga8PErbr9NQihbp/0).

---

**The dynamic solution** aims at reproducing that exact same query as a prepared statement (which is essentially a string that you first build and then ask MySQL to execute over the database), with the only difference that it needs to generalize on the amount of fields to extract:

```
MAX(IF(rn_add = 1, addition, NULL)) AS addition1,
MAX(IF(rn_qst = 1, addition, NULL)) AS question1,
    ...
    ...
MAX(IF(rn_add = <n>, addition, NULL)) AS addition<n>,
MAX(IF(rn_qst = <n>, addition, NULL)) AS question<n>,
```

And we need to reproduce these instructions *n* times with *n* equals to the *item_id*'s highest amount of both *addition* and *question* values. In order to generate this piece of query, we get the longest list of indices:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item_id) AS idx
    FROM tab
)
```

and cycle over it to generate all `MAX` rows as a string where, in place of the specific number (as in the static query), we will use all the numbers stored inside *cte.idx*:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT('MAX(IF(rn_add = ', cte.idx, ', addition, NULL)) AS addition', cte.idx, ','
                  'MAX(IF(rn_qst = ', cte.idx, ', question, NULL)) AS question', cte.idx
       )) INTO @sql
FROM cte;
```

Once we have the generalized amonut of `MAX` rows, we can just use this together with the rest of the static query, which does not depend on the number of *addition* or *question* values.

```
SET @cte = 'WITH cte AS(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, surname ORDER BY IF(addition IS NULL, 1, 0), ID) AS rn_add, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, surname ORDER BY IF(question IS NULL, 1, 0), ID) AS rn_qst FROM tab)';

SET @sql = CONCAT(@cte,
                  'SELECT item_id AS ID, item_id, name, surname,',
                  @sql,
                  ',SUM(amount) AS amount FROM cte GROUP BY item_id, name, surname'
);
```

Once we have the static query generated as a string in a dynamic way, we can ask MySQL to prepare, execute and deallocate it.

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

The execution will show you your desired output.

Here's the full code for the dynamic query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

WITH cte AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item_id) AS idx
    FROM tab
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT('MAX(IF(rn_add = ', cte.idx, ', addition, NULL)) AS addition', cte.idx, ','
                  'MAX(IF(rn_qst = ', cte.idx, ', question, NULL)) AS question', cte.idx
       )) INTO @sql
FROM cte;

SET @cte = 'WITH cte AS(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, surname ORDER BY IF(addition IS NULL, 1, 0), ID) AS rn_add, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, surname ORDER BY IF(question IS NULL, 1, 0), ID) AS rn_qst FROM tab)';

SET @sql = CONCAT(@cte,
                  'SELECT item_id AS ID, item_id, name, surname,',
                  @sql,
                  ',SUM(amount) AS amount FROM cte GROUP BY item_id, name, surname'
);

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u8TxS4EzKecQDE9VLLBGKP/0).

---

**Side Note**: if you want to store the output of this query, you may require to create a view inside the prepared statement. In that case you should change the *@sql* assignment to:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW my_view AS ',
                  @cte,
                  'SELECT item_id AS ID, item_id, name, surname,',
                  @sql,
                  ',SUM(amount) AS amount FROM cte GROUP BY item_id, name, surname'
);
```

hence select the content of the view whenever you need it, for example to export it to Excel.

Comment: Thanks for very good answer @lemon :) 
I update my question after a few attempts to write this query. 
Not sure whats wrong

Comment: If you can catch the differences between the sql demo published here and your data, I may help you further @Hub

Comment: did it solve your problem then?

Comment: the difference is adding left joins instead of tab table @lemon

Comment: there is a mistake somewhere in my query, i get message "Duplicate column name 'id'. " @lemon
I stucked here

Comment: yes,
needs a moment

Comment: Typically that error is due when you join two tables and each of the two tables have the same column field, then it does not know where to pick that column from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815627/1060-duplicate-column-name-id. Can you create a fiddle for debugging at https://www.db-fiddle.com/? @Hub

Comment: i put fiddle for debugging demo in edit2 of my post @lemon.
Sorry for so long, but I had to edit my tables

Comment: Do you have a query that gets you successfully from the fiddle tables to the input table published in this post? @Hub

Comment: yes, query similar to Stu answer.
I seved it in fiddle

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZ1nYthiEMsJxKcUgUrGSp/6 can you tell me if this is the static output you need? (once we get the static one working, the dynamic is easy) @Hub

Comment: why there's the same user_id for different combination of (name, surname)? @Hub this detail conflicts with the creation of the final table

Comment: oh, thats why in fiddle doesn't works. 
Thanks to you, I was able to create something like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZ1nYthiEMsJxKcUgUrGSp/8
In db it works but in fiddle no, propably because of Views? @lemon

user_id is diffrent by my mistake

Comment: If you ask about table `event_items` ? @lemon

Comment: In the first generated table I've changed `event_items.user_id` to `users.id AS user_id`. Here's a reference to the updated static version https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZ1nYthiEMsJxKcUgUrGSp/10 and to the dynamic one https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZ1nYthiEMsJxKcUgUrGSp/9. Does it solve your problem? @Hub

Comment: Great! I understand very well now :) It solvs the problem! @lemon
Thanks

Comment: How you can call this type of query? Its posible to write it without concatenate (in one big query)? @lemon

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. Dynamic query generation requires multiple steps, namely 1. the query to cycle over the variable (`cte.idx`), 2. the query to build the string (`SET @sql = ....`), 3. the transformation from the string to the prepared statement (`PREPARE @sql`), 4. the execution of the prepared statement (`EXECUTE @sql`), 5. the deallocation of the prepared statement (`DEALLOCATE @sql`). @Hub

Comment: If you want to "*call*" this set of instructions, you need to put them inside a stored procedure. Check here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html @Hub

Answer (score 2):

Will just throw this here as a possibility - it won't give you dynamic columns but may be of use depending on how you intend to consume the data.

It's certaintly less faff and more performant if you can.

```
select 
    item_Id, name, surname, 
    group_concat(addition separator ', ') Additions,
    group_concat(question separator ', ') Questions,
    Sum(amount) amount
from t
group by item_Id, name, surname;
```